# PHP CSV file parsing sterling and euro symbol

Tags: php, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have an UTF-8 encoded (with Save as with encoding..) CSV file with rows with [name, currency+amount] format, being currency either "$", € or £.

Eg:

```
1;"01/05/2010";"£50.00"
2;"01/05/2010";"$66.10"
2;"02/05/2010";"€12.00"
```

What I need is to parse the CSV rows and try to check/match those symbols somehow, to be used next in an array of "exchange rate currencies" for example.

EDITED: I'm printing my results to a BASH/DOS console, NOT to a browser.

Actually when I dump in the stdout console it prints "garbage" (I assume UTF-8 code) as `"┬ú"` for Sterling and `"Γé¼"` for Euro.

When trying to do iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $row), the euro get to "EUR" with I can handle fine, but the pound throws an error.

Also, using PHP functions utf8_* is not working, as they encode or decode to ISO-8859 afaik.

Comment: Thats not a Comma Seperated Variable file  its a Simi Colon Seperated Variable file

Comment: Try converting your script file to utf-8 as well

Comment: How do you load the csv file please provide a sample code.

Comment: How have you tried to load it?

Comment: The parsing is fine, I mean, the data is retrieved correctly, that's whay I didn't enter parse code. My problem was handling the characters of the result set.

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, what do you mean regarding if a tried to load it?

Comment: Hi, just FYI, a friend of mine tested this in a Mac OS with PHP 5.6.30 CLI and it worked great. I just downloaded PHP 7.1.5 and amazingly worked great. So I would say that PHP 5.6.14 stills create some issues with UTF-8 (which BTW is almost deprecated)